# xamarin - How i am able to show the tool bar item text, show the front value instead of behind

Tags: xamarin

i am using xamarin to code the project. Now i encounter one issue which is, i added one tool bar item with text, if it is showing the short text it is fine, however if the text is too long, the tool bar item text is showing the behind value since it is too long. for eg "today i want to play football with peter", the xamarin show "play football with peter", however i want to show the front value which is "today i want to play",is it able to achieve it? or i am required to do a substring?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin Forms, there is no way to control this (currently).  The underlying logic used to abbreviate a string is controlled by the platform, and Forms does not expose any control over this for Toolbar items.

You could write a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) that used the underlying platform API to control how a string is abbreviated.  However, it would probably be much easier to just use shorter strings for ToolbarItems that did not require abbreviation.